# DUDA PHP Y JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, fpdf

Mi duda es que no se como enlazar mi `PHP` con `JAVASCRIPT`, el usuario se busca ingresando su `ID`, y se abre una nueva pestaña, me gustaría saber como puedo colocar un mensaje de alerta con `JAVASCRIPT` para indicar que el `ID` no esta registrado en el mismo `index.php`

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,
                  "SELECT primer_nombre, primer_apellido, curp from nacional where cedula='$cedula'"));

if (!$res){
    die("ID no encontrado");


?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<button type="button" onclick="location.href='index.php'">VOLVER</button>
alert("HOLA MUNDO");


<?php
}
$primer_nombre = utf8_decode($res[0]);
$primer_apellido = utf8_decode($res[1]);
$curp = $res[2];
```

Comment: No deberías mezclar así el código, por otro lado sería más simple una petición Ajax en la cual viajen los datos del form y como respuesta obtengamos tal vez un json que podamos manipular en la vista

Comment: ¿Por qué mostrar alerta con javascript? Si no estás procesando el formulario por AJAX va a aparecer una página vacía y la ventana de diálogo del navegador. Si estás procesando por AJAX, lo ideal sería devolver un dato y, desde javascript, manejar cómo se va a presentar.

Comment: Deberías evitar la mezcla de código PHP/JavaScript en un mismo archivo. Esto se suele hacer con Ajax (mucho más alegante y eficiente porque te permite llevar y traer información entre cliente y servidor sin tener que recargar la página). Además vas a necesitar Ajax sí o sí para el problema de la fecha/hora que planteaste en otra pregunta. Y también me permito señalar que tu código es un falso positivo, la forma en que controlas la existencia de datos no es real, mediante la verificación de `$res` no sabrás con certeza que el ID no fue encontrado, tienes que verificar el número de filas.

Answer (score 0):

Quieres que muestre un alerta si no encuentra nada en la búsqueda, pero estas matando el resto de código al colocarle la función `die()` de **PHP**.
Aquí te dejo el mismo código pero con algunos errores resuelto:

```
$res = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,
                  "SELECT primer_nombre, primer_apellido, curp from nacional where cedula='$cedula'"));

if (!$res){
    echo "<script>alert('El ID no fue encontrado')</script>";

}
$primer_nombre = utf8_decode($res[0]);
$primer_apellido = utf8_decode($res[1]);
$curp = $res[2];
```

Comment: Seguro que ese fragmento de javascript incrustado en PHP va a funcionar?

Comment: Me parece ese javascript debe ser impreso mediante echo pues así como está no hace parte de la sintaxis de PHP y dará error

Comment: @BetaM es cierto, no pensé en eso, pero existe una forma de que funcione con JavaScript, aunque lo mejor es escribir un `echo` y listo

Comment: Y también existe otra forma para poner el script, pero es que el código de nuestro amigo esta un poco extraño, juzgando con que quiere hacer código espagueti mezclando 2 lenguajes. De todos modos ahora mismo edito la respuesta.

Comment: Esta respuesta podría funcionar.
Solo que yo lo colocaría así:
echo "<script>alert('El ID no fue encontrado')</script>";
exit;
Porque estás colocando: die() y eso detiene la ejecución de todo el script php. Con exit tambien la detienes.

Answer (score -2):

Creo que el problema es que tu `<script></script>` no está cerrado.

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta, cuando tengas la suficiente reputación podrás dejar comentarios en cualquier publicación. Te sugiero que elimines esta respuesta ya que no es realmente una respuesta. Saludos